# How to prevent scrollTop from changing when tabbed to hidden element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a box with `overflow: hidden` where some elements are positioned outside of the box

When I tab through to the elements outside of the box, the box is actually shifting or scrolling, even though it's not supposed to because of `overflow: hidden`

http://jsbin.com/rabetib/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Notice that you shouldn't be able to see the non-yellow boxes, but the container changes scroll position when tabbing

Is there another CSS/HTML/JS prop that can prevent my box from moving to show focused item?

My only solution right now is to repeatedly set `scrollTop: 0` whenever focus changes

Comment: Providing some sample code will help.

Comment: @freginold added

Comment: May I ask why you want that behaviour, what are you doing with it?

Comment: @RomanCortes I found a solution, but the reason is because we have physics that are absolutely positioning elements, and we avoided using DOM scroll since they aren't linear or uni-directional movements, even though user can still use wheel or touchmove to "fling" the forms around. It's possible that we could have used DOM scrolls, but I remember getting blocked by things like decimal values, our scroll vs user scroll, dynamic heights maybe

Comment: Just thinking that if you are able on time to use a transform for the content but leave the scrollTop as is, you can animate your physics but have everything: up/down key support, wheel, scrollbar... I mean transform negatively to compensate for the scroll

Answer (score 2):

Ok so, the way I fixed this problem is to listen for `scroll` on the container.

It's too late to call `e.preventDefault()`, but you can set `container.scrollTop = 0` after the erroneous scroll. No flash on my version of chrome